# It is possible to find at least one function satisfying both $a)$ and $b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality

Let $a<1$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. I am looking for a function $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ satisfying both
$$a)\quad f^{\prime}(x)\ge \frac{1}{x^2} \qquad \mbox{ for } 0<x<\varepsilon;$$
$$b)\quad f(x)\ge \frac{1}{x^a} \qquad \mbox{ for } 0<x<\varepsilon.$$

About me, some examples can be found only when $a<0$. I am not sure, but maybe one example can be constructed in this way: take $a=-1$ and $f(x) = x$. Thus $f(x)$ satisfies $b)$ and $f^{\prime}(x) =1$ satisfies $a)$ for $x>1$,i.e you can take $\varepsilon=2$ and $a)$ is satisfied for $1<x<2$, but not in the range $0<x<1$ (this is the reason why I am not convinced).

Could someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Condition (a) already implies that $f(x)$ is not bounded below, by the fundamental theorem of calculus (consider $\int_\eta^{\varepsilon/2} f'(x)\,dx$ as $\eta\to 0^+$).

Comment: Condition $1$ implies $f$ is increasing on $(0,\epsilon)$ as well as $|f(x)|  \to \infty, x\to 0$ 
(as per @Greg comment $f$ is unbounded near zero and monotonicity implies the limit at zero  exists so it must be $-\infty$) and those imply that $f<0$ for small enough $\epsilon$ which makes $2$ impossible, so there is no function that works

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you for your comment. Could you please better explain how to use fundamental theorem of calculus to prove that $f$ is not bounded from below?

Comment: Have you evaluated $\int_\eta^{\varepsilon/2} f'(x) \,dx$? Have you replaced $f'(x)$ by its lower bound and evaluated that related integral?

Comment: @GregMartin it should be $f(x)=\int_{\eta}^{\varepsilon/2} f^{\prime}(x) dx \ge \int_{\eta}^{\varepsilon/2} \frac{1}{x^2} dx =[-1/x]_{\eta}^{\varepsilon/2} =-2/\varepsilon +1/\eta$ which goes to $+\infty$ as $\eta\to 0$. Did you mean this?

Comment: @Conrad why do you say that the limit near $0$ is $-\infty$?

Comment: Because $f$ is increasing since $f' \ge 0$; this means that if $a_n$ decreases to zero, we have $f(a_n)$ decreases but $|f(a_n)|$ is unbounded so the limit is $-\infty$!

Comment: @Conrad sorry, it is still not clear for me. And why $|f(a_n)|$ is unbounded? It shouldn't be $f(a_n)|$?

Comment: put a short answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a function.

First, point $a$ means $f' \ge 0$ so $f$ increases for  $0<x<\varepsilon$ which means that for example as $n \to \infty, f(1/n)$ decreases to some $L$ which can be finite or $-\infty$

But if $L$ would be finite, if we fix such an $n$ large enough so $0<1/n <\varepsilon$, one has $f(1/n)=\int_{1/m}^{1/n}f'(x)dx+f(1/m) \ge \int_{1/m}^{1/n}\frac{1}{x^2}dx+f(1/m) \ge m-n+L$ for all $m >n$ which means that $f(1/n)=\infty$ and that is not possible.

Hence $L$ must be $-\infty$ and since $f$ monotonic, it follows that $f(x) \to -\infty, x \to 0, x >0$ so in particular $f(x)<0$ for $x>0$ small enough contradicting point $b$

Comment: thank you for the answer. But why if $f(1/n)\ge m-n+L$ thus you say that $f(1/n)=\infty$?

Comment: $\int_{1/m}^{1/n}\frac{1}{x^2}dx=m-n$ and $f(1/m) \ge L$ since $f(1/m)$ decreases to $L$

Comment: and then $m>n$ arbitrary so $f(1/n) \ge m-C$ for all $m >n$ means $f(1/n)=\infty$